# Rust rdkafka subscription reporting invalid offsets

Tags: rust, apache-kafka

I am attempting to write some Rust code which can be used to obtain information about the current maximum offset value for partitions in a Kafka cluster.

There is an example of how to do this [here](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/metadata.rs).

The above example is not ideal for what I am trying to do for the following reason:

- The consumer `fetch_metadata` call appears to return all metadata for the cluster it has connected to. This means that information about *all* topics is retuned, whereas I aim to build something which can return information only about topics which a consumer is going to subscribe to.

I made two attempts to do this. Here is some example code. In both cases, I could not get any sensible data out. In both cases I got "INVALID" offset values.

---

Here is example 1:

```
consumer.subscribe(&topic_names).unwrap();

// attempted to call poll hoping this would "initialize"
// the offset values returned. it doesn't seem to make
// a difference whether or not this is included
let something = consumer.poll(poll_duration);

// this method attempts to get the topic names and offsets
// using information from `subscription()`
let subscription = consumer.subscription().unwrap();


let topic_map = subscription.to_topic_map();

for (key, offset) in topic_map.into_iter() {
    let topic_name = key.0;
    let partition_number = key.1;
    let offset = offset.to_raw();

    println!("topic_name={}, partition_number={}, offset={:?}", topic_name, partition_number, offset);
}
```

This method returns this:

```
topic_name=topic_name_removed, partition_number=-1, offset=Some(-1001)
```

---

This is Example 2:

```
consumer.subscribe(&topic_names).unwrap();

// as before, attempted to call `poll()` here,
// but no change in behavior. call to poll
// omitted here

// this method attempts to get the offsets
// using information from `position()` function
// call
let position = consumer.position().unwrap();

let position_elements = position.elements();

log::warn!("printing position elements");
for position_element in position_elements {
    println!("topic: {:?}", position_element.topic());
    println!("error: {:?}", position_element.error());
    println!("partition: {:?}", position_element.partition());
    println!("offset: {:?}", position_element.offset());
    println!("metadata: {:?}", position_element.metadata());
}
```

This prints a *lot* of information, but all of the offset values are invalid. Here is just part of the returned information.

```
topic: "HIDDEN"
error: Ok(())
partition: 0
offset: Invalid
metadata: ""
```

---

In both cases, I seem to get invalid topic offsets. I don't understand why this is happening, and I would have expected "poll" to have caused the offset to become something sensible if it had previously been invalid. But this does not seem to be the observed behaviour.